# Long keypress down and up for react select virtualized not working for more than 2000 data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I am using react-select v5 + react-virtualized + react hooks! https://github.com/guiyep/react-select-virtualized for creating a dropdown for more than 3000 options. The issue I am facing there is when I press key down button for longer duration, it gets stuck and selection disappears from the dropdown.

What I tried different is , I used react-select and went through the resolutions mentioned in https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/3128 but nothing fixed the long press key down issue.

I tried using these 2 examples as well, but they only work for large data sets and key press  issue is still there

Example with react-window codesandbox.
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-large-list-ug2f2

Update:

Example with react-virtuoso codesandbox.

https://codesandbox.io/s/s9hfk

Please let me know any solutions for that

Comment: Well material ui auto complete fixes that issue, but still looking for this issue answer